# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: api, pdo, rest

estoy desarrollando una `API` con  `slim framework 3` que conecta a una `base de datos` local. El problema es el siguiente cuando intento realizar una actualización a algun elemento de mi `BD` pasandole un `id` dicho procedimiento me devuelve el siguiente error **"{"error": {"text": SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where idEspecialidad = 1' at line 2}"**

especialidad.php

```
    <?php

    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->group('/especialidad/', function () {
    $this-> put('actualizar/{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');

    $nombre = $request->getParam('nombre');


    $sql = "update especialidad set nombre =:nombre ,
            where idEspecialidad = $id"; 

    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Especialidad Actualizada"}';

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage(). '}';
    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es debido a una sintaxis incorrecta aquí:

<s>`update especialidad set nombre =:nombre , where idEspecialidad = $id`</s>

**Hay una `,` antes del `where`**.

Ahora bien, tienes un serio problema de seguridad, al estar pasando el valor `$id` directamente. Ese valor tiene que ser pasado también aparte, como haces con el valor `:nombre`.

Como dato adicional, es totalmente válido pasar los parámetros en el `execute`, sin tener que recurrir a `bindParam`, por eso verás que he creado un `$arrParams`, en el cual creo los parámetros y luego los paso en el `execute`. Te ahorrará algunas líneas de código, sobre todo en consultas con muchos parámetros.

He aquí el código corregido:

```
    <?php

    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->group('/especialidad/', function () {
    $this-> put('actualizar/{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');

    $nombre = $request->getParam('nombre');


    $sql = "update especialidad set nombre =:nombre 
            where idEspecialidad =:id"; 

    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $arrParams=array(':nombre'=>$_POST['nombre'], ':id'=>$id);
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($arrParams);
        $db = null;

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Especialidad Actualizada"}';

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage(). '}';
    }

});

});
```

Comment: He reemplazado el código, por el código corregido y cuando intento realizar la actualización me devuelve un error en la linea 116  que corresponde con ` $arrParams=array(':nombre'=>$_POST['nombre'], ':id'=>$id);` luego muestra el mensaje de confirmación, pero en mi tabla el nombre aparece vacio.

Comment: Tenía duda sobre cuál sería la variable `$nombre` en realidad, ya que aquí tú tienes esto: `$nombre = $request->getParam('nombre');`, entonces no sé por qué tienes eso y tienes otro valor venido por `POST`, como quiera que sea, si el nombre aparece vacío, significa que no está pasando datos por `POST`. ¿Acaso envías el nombre desde otra parte, un formulario por ejemplo? Si es así, debes verificar que ese dato se está llenando, para eso puedes usar **`if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){ //Código de actualización}else{echo "No se pasó ningún nombre en el POST";}`**

Comment: `nombre` es un atributo de mi clase especialidad dentro de la `bd`, yo lo q intento hacer es modificar (actualizar) el valor de ese atributo x uno q yo le pase, el `idEspecialista` es el `id` de mi clase q se autogenera cuando se agrega una nueva especialidad. Agregue el `if` y me devuelve q `no se encontro ningun nombre en el POST`

Comment: @Germanccho, pues si se lo pasas por POST, desde un formulario o desde una URL, debes asegurarte que el formulario tiene un elemento (generalmente un input text), con el atributo `name="nombre"`). Si es por una URL, la misma debería tener un valor como este: `www.archivo.php?nombre=Nombre nuevo que usarás`. Si está saliendo en blanco es porque ese valor no se está pasando. **¿Desde dónde estás enviando el nuevo valor para `nombre`?**

Comment: Si envías una petición `PUT` el dato no estará en la superglobal `$_POST`.  Podrías probar obteniendo el nombre de `$request->getParsedBodyParam('nombre');`